# Error: "no main manifest attribute, in Elevator.jar"

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar, artifact, discord-jda

I am working on a private Discord bot, where I use json files to store values. My bot runs perfectly in IntelliJ. I created a .jar file using the Artifact feature, but when I try to run it, I get the error: `no main manifest attribute, in Elevator.jar`. I used Git bash to run it using the command `java -jar Elevator.jar`. I use maven, a json library and a JDA library (for Discord integration).

Is my pom.xml file wrong, or can I not use json files for a .jar? if so, how can I execute my code without running intellij? If I need to add more code or give more info please ask.

Notes:

- The package is sebastiaan.Elevator
- I used File -> project structure -> Artifacts -> Add -> JAR -> from modules with dependencies, selected the correct main class and pressed OK. I then clicked Build -> Build Artifact -> Build to create the file

[picture of my jar file (using winrar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY78Q.png)

[picture of my jar file META-INF folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIIHB.png)

My MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: sebastiaan.Elevator.Main
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Elevator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Where did you put your manifest file? Did you check it is packaged into the jar file, e.g. by looking into it with a zip-file viewer?

Comment: See `maven-compiler-plugin` first has `source` and `target` `8`, and then `5`. May be its a problem.

Comment: @Thomas When I look into the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, I get: 
```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: Benjamin
Build-Jdk: 1.4.2_19
```
Im not sure what to make of this, if this is correct or not (I am not Benjamin)

Comment: @AnsarOzden I tried removing the 5 but it broke my program (weird errors)

Comment: see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html
try 1.8 instead of 8

Comment: That manifest doesn't seem right as you couldn't have built the jar with JDK 1.4.2 and source level 5. Did you look into the jar file you built (check by timestamp)?

Comment: @AnsarOzden I did what you sent me and after a few code edits (some methods stopped working) the program worked in IntelliJ, but the jar file gives the same result

Comment: @Thomas Im sorry I don't know what you mean

Comment: I looked into the jar file but there are a lot of files and folders

Comment: I see you include plugin `maven-compiler-plugin` in `dependencies`. I think, better write plugin version in `plugin` area and delete plugin record from `dependencies`.

Comment: @AnsarOzden edited the pom again :P thanks

Comment: @Thomas I included a screenshot of my jar file, maybe it helps

Comment: @Thomas I replaced the manifest of my jar file with the one in my src folder, when I now try to run it, it successfully runs the main() method (I get console logs), but it fails at locating the json files and throws errors

Comment: Well, those json files might need to be packaged into the jar file as well or maybe need to be located next to it. I don't know which files and how the application tries to load them so I can't tell more - it would probably be a separate question anyway.

Comment: I asked a new question, because Eclipse builds the jar successfully, but I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67753834/executable-jar-file-cant-find-json-files

Comment: BTW, you define the java8 dependency twice, once for the compiler plugin, and once in the properties (which the compiler plugin reads). You can safely omit either the configuration section or the properties to avoid duplication

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a main class manifest in the pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

See more examples [here](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html)